# How long does it take for furosemide/lasix to be effective in a cat?

Tags: cats, medicines

Hunter was recently diagnosed with restrictive [cardiomyopathy](http://www.vcahospitals.com/main/pet-health-information/article/animal-health/heart-disease-cardiomyopathy-in-cats/61) (a heart condition that led to fluid accumulating in his heart and lungs).

We were instructed to monitor his condition by measuring his breathing rate regularly. To do this, we should count the number of breaths (an inhalation and exhalation) that he takes in a minute. We were instructed to do this when he is relaxed or asleep.

Hunter is currently receiving 10 mg of furosemide (lasix) every 12 hours to reduce fluid retention in his lungs. We were instructed to administer an additional dose (10 mg) if his breathing rate becomes elevated (normal for him is about 22 breaths per minute). We were further instructed that if his breathing rate continues to be elevated (or is above 40 breaths per minute) we should take him to the nearest emergency vet.

When I have to give him an additional dose of furosemide, how long should I expect it to take to become effective? If his breathing rate is elevated but below 40 bpm, how long should I monitor him before taking him to the emergency vet?